# How to prevent multiple instances of the same window from opening in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, nswindowcontroller

I am making a Mac Menu Bar app and it has a `Preferences` option. When the user clicks on it, a `Preferences` window opens up that shows all the settings for the app.

I open the `Preferences` window like:

```
let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "PreferencesWindowController") as! NSWindowController
windowController.showWindow(self)
```

*File: AppDelegate.swift (above code is run when user clicks on "Preferences")*

Now, if the user clicks twice then **two** `Preferences` windows open up which I do not want. I only want one "Preferences" window to open even if the user clicks multiple times.

I can, of course, create a boolean flag here and toggle and check before opening the window but wanted to know whether there is any API (cleaner way) to achieve this?

Comment: Make it lazy so you have a reference to it once’s it’s initialized. https://github.com/DanielStormApps/Fanny/blob/c3f010848ccb12d986a1b8755fe4c5cc25728484/Fanny/fanny/Menu/FNYMenuController.swift#L24

Comment: @DanielStorm if you wish you can answer the same and I can accept it

Comment: Thanks. That’s ok though. I’m on my phone so it is kind of a pain to format an answer correctly. Feel free to answer your own question and accept it when you’re able to 